# UltraGrid Currency Cell Showing 4 Decimal Places

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I've not had this issue before when using `UltraGrid` controls. I'm setting the `.DataSource` of my grid to be a `DataTable`, will if filled using records selected from a SQL Server database.

One of the columns, "Fee", needs to be in currency format. To do this, in my `InitializeLayout` event, I've got this line to validate this.

```
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("Fee").Format = "C"
```

The validation works in the sense that is shows a £ sign in front of the value, however, when I load data into the grid and click a row's "Fee" cell, the cell shows 750.0000, rather than just 750 or 750.00

Whenever I've set the `.Format` to "C" before, I've never encountered this. What else could it be, or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the data type of the column "Fee" is decimal. It is absolutely normal to see the raw value with full representation of the floating point number in edit mode.

However, if you would like to round this number and show, let's say, only the first two floating point digits, you can handle `BeforeCellActivate` event handler and use [Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Of course, the rest of the floating point digits would be lost, but reading the given example, this does not seem to be the case in your scenario.

Here is code snippet:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ultraGrid1.BeforeCellActivate += new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CancelableCellEventHandler(ultraGrid1_BeforeCellActivate);
        this.ultraGrid1.DataSource = InitializeDataSource();
        this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Format = "C";
    }

    private void ultraGrid1_BeforeCellActivate(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CancelableCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "Fee")
        {
            e.Cell.Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(e.Cell.Value), 2);
        }
    }

    private DataTable InitializeDataSource()
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("Fee", typeof(decimal));

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { i * new Random().NextDouble() });
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This `BeforeCellActivate` method hasn't resolved the issue, it still shows to 4 decimal places.

Comment: Did you test my entire sample as it is or tried to implement it in your project only? Are you sure that the new value is really shorten and you make the conversion for the right column?

Comment: I implemented it into my project - I'm not using the `Private DataTable` block, only the `BeforeCellActivate` method. I'm definitely using the correct column, too

Answer (score 0):

Try using "C2" as the format and see if that fixes it.

Note that this would format 750 to $750.00 so if you wanted $750 that's still an issue.

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into that matter, seems pretty strange that you are getting the following behavior:

> The validation works in the sense that is shows a £ sign in front of the value, however, when I load data into the grid and click a row's "Fee" cell, the cell shows 750.0000, rather than just 750 or 750.00

The correct part is that you should get your currency sign like you said, and the formatting would have to be that as well when not in edit mode:  £ 750.00

However the other part, when in edit mode is strange. The editor would really show the raw value that you have in your DataTable column, but if it is either "750.00000000" or "750.00000", it would simply show the whole number - "750" instead, and not "750.0000".

What is the exact value that you have in that row, prior the column is being set to currency?

Also if you are properly hooked to the `ultraGrid1_BeforeCellActivate` event of the UltraGrid, and have there a method like `Math.Round`

```
if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "Fee")
        {
            e.Cell.Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(e.Cell.Value), 2);
        }
```

You would end up, with only 2 digits after the whole number, regardless of the exact value in the DataTable.

What version of the Infragistics controls you are using in your application? Are there any other changes, or settings being applied to your UltraGrid?

**Edit:**

On another note, if you still experience the same behavior after all of those changes, it would mean that some systems continue to do that, and still show 4 decimal places, when in Edit Mode, in case when dealing with Data Columns which DataType is Decimal. So you would have two possibilities to change that:

1. Change the underlying data type of the "Fee" data column to "Double", and you won't have that behavior anymore.
2. If you can not perform number 1, for some reason, than you would have to play with the MaskInput property of the "Fee" column, which would give you the ability to change what you see while in Edit Mode like:

   ```
       private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
   {

       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Fee"].Format = "C";

       //Set the mask to be in the following format:
       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Fee"].MaskInput = "nnnn.nn";

       //If you would like to see the £ as well, you could use the one instead:
       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Fee"].MaskInput = "£nnnnn.nn";

       //If you would like to change the under score (_), with another char like empty space ( ) you could do it like that:
       e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Fee"].PromptChar = ' ';
   }
   ```